# Create password and write it to file

Tags: ansible

The idea is to generate user accounts over an API. Using default variables as the basic information:

```
---
students:
  - Username: testuser1
    E-Mail: student1@student.com
  - Username: testuser2
    E-Mail: student2@student.com
```

The `Creating User` role will then create all users with the API:

```
- name: "Creating User"
  uri:
    url: "https://URL/api/v1/users"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: AUTH TOKEN
    body:
      name: "{{ item['Username'] }}"
      email: "{{ item['E-Mail'] }}"
      password: "{{ item['Password'] }}"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
  loop: "{{ students }}"
```

I can not find a way to generate a password for each user and write them to a file. Is there a way I can append a `Password` variable to each student item before the `Creating User` role? If so I could just write the default variable to a file as a last role.

I've played with the password module. I do not want to have 100+ files with the passwords of the users. I need to have a singe file at the end with all information.

Comment: Please see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/password_lookup.html

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, I know of that module but this is not the issue and does not help.

Comment: You appently missed a part of the doc: `A special case is using /dev/null as a path`. You can therefore use the lookup to create a password for each user and (re)create a datastructure containing the password, then store everything in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question.

The below will take your actual user list, create a new one with a generated password for each and store the result in a single file for all users. Bonus: if the file exists, the var will be initialized from there bypassing the password creation.

**Notes**:

- The below can be enhanced. You can put the block tasks for file creation in a separate file and use a conditional include so that the skipped loop iteration do not take place at all when the file already exists.
- I obviously did not take security into account here and I strongly suggest you secure the way your file is stored.

**Demo playbook**:

```yaml
---
- name: Create random passwords and store
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    users_with_pass_file: /tmp/test_pass.txt

    students:
      - Username: testuser1
        E-Mail: student1@student.com
      - Username: testuser2
        E-Mail: student2@student.com

  tasks:

    - name: Try to load users and passwords from file if it exists
      vars:
        file_content: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', users_with_pass_file, errors='ignore') }}"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        users_with_pass: "{{ file_content }}"
      when:
        - file_content | length > 0
        # Unfortunately, there is no test 'is list' in jinja2...
        - file_content is iterable
        - file_content is not mapping
        - file_content is not string
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
      register: load_from_disk

    - name: Create user list with passwords and store it if it does not exists (or is malformed...)
      block:

        - name: Create the list
          vars:
            user_password: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.password', '/dev/null', length=12) }}"
          ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            users_with_pass: "{{ users_with_pass | default([]) + [item | combine({'password': user_password})] }}"
          loop: "{{ students }}"

        - name: Store the result
          ansible.builtin.copy:
            dest: "{{ users_with_pass_file }}"
            content: "{{ users_with_pass | to_json }}"

      when: load_from_disk is skipped or load_from_disk is failed

    - name: Show the result
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: users_with_pass
```

**first run** (with used ansible version):

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.10.1
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) [GCC 8.4.0]

$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Create random passwords and store] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Try to load users and passwords from file if it exists] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/tmp/test_pass.txt' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Create the list] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Username': 'testuser1', 'E-Mail': 'student1@student.com'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Username': 'testuser2', 'E-Mail': 'student2@student.com'})

TASK [Store the result] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Show the result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_with_pass": [
        {
            "E-Mail": "student1@student.com",
            "Username": "testuser1",
            "password": "5l1RG7HzqaKMWJcH:mRH"
        },
        {
            "E-Mail": "student2@student.com",
            "Username": "testuser2",
            "password": "tZvLT3LVj3_60GV_WoQd"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Second run:**

```
PLAY [Create random passwords and store] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Try to load users and passwords from file if it exists] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create the list] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Username': 'testuser1', 'E-Mail': 'student1@student.com'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Username': 'testuser2', 'E-Mail': 'student2@student.com'}) 

TASK [Store the result] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show the result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_with_pass": [
        {
            "E-Mail": "student1@student.com",
            "Username": "testuser1",
            "password": "5l1RG7HzqaKMWJcH:mRH"
        },
        {
            "E-Mail": "student2@student.com",
            "Username": "testuser2",
            "password": "tZvLT3LVj3_60GV_WoQd"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have diceware installed, then you can generate the password:

```
- name: generate new password
  delegate_to: localhost
  command: diceware --no-caps -d ' ' -w en_eff
  register: generatedpass
```

Then you can store in the file:

```
- name: store password
  copy:
    dest: '/path/to/password/file'
    content: |
      {{ generatedpass }}
```

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick.